# Get all product information

Tags: magento-1.9, products, product-collection

How to display all **Product Information** in particular **Attribute set**  like Product name , sku , attributes etc..

It shows Attribute Name & Id but i want all details like Product name , sku , attributes etc..

```
<?php
      require_once('app/Mage.php');
      umask(0);
      Mage::app();//->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
      $entityType = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId();
      $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')->setEntityTypeFilter($entityType);
      $allSet = array();
      foreach($collection as $coll){
         $attributeSet['name'] = $coll->getAttributeSetName();
         $attributeSet['id'] = $coll->getAttributeSetId();
         $allSet[] = $attributeSet;
      }
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($allSet);
      echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

First, filter whatever attributes you need from the collection:

```
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('sku')->addAttributeToSelect('name');
```

Then loop through these products and do what you want

```
foreach ($_products as $product){
    $sku = $product->getData('sku');
    echo $sku . '<br>';
     // generally
    $attribute = $product->getData('attribute');

}
```

Comment: I want based on attribute set

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of attributes for each attribute set you can use:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_api')->items($attributeSetId);
```

Try with this code:

```
        ...
        $entityType = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId();
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')->setEntityTypeFilter($entityType);
        $allSet = array();
        foreach($collection as $coll){
            $attributeSet['name'] = $coll->getAttributeSetName();
            $attributeSet['id'] = $coll->getAttributeSetId();

            $attributeSet['attributes'] = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_api')->items($coll->getAttributeSetId());

            $allSet[] = $attributeSet;
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($allSet);
        echo "</pre>";
        ...
```

Comment: What i need to echo this

Comment: Can you please be more clear?

Comment: let us assume i want to display in front end i created file in root path and then i call

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand what you need.

Comment: localhost/my.php when i run want to display here

Comment: Magento does not work this way. You need to create at least a module and a  controller and include the above code inside. Otherwise just try to paste my code inside your script. But it is not the right way to do it.

Comment: Sorry localhost/root/my.php i try but not working

Answer (score 0):

Try below code..

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToselect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('sku','value')->addAttributeToFilter('name','value')->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id','setid');
```

This query will fetch data of all attribute & filter with the attribute name for the specific attribute set.
If you don't want to get all attribute try this

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToselect('sku')->addAttributeToselect('name')->addAttributeToFilter('sku','value')->addAttributeToFilter('name','value')->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id','setid');
```

Answer (score 0):

==> Almost all Magento Models have a corresponding Collection object that can be used to fetch multiple instances of a Model.

==> To instantiate a Product collection, do the following

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

==> Products are a Magento EAV style Model, so you'll need to add on any additional attributes that you want to return.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

//fetch name and orig_price into data

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');  
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('orig_price');
```

==> There's multiple syntaxes for setting filters on collections. I always use the verbose one below, but you might want to inspect the Magento source for additional ways the filtering methods can be used.

==> The following shows how to filter by a range of values (greater than AND less than)

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');  
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('orig_price');
```

//filter for products whose orig_price is greater than (gt) 100

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'orig_price','gt'=>'100'),
));
```

//AND filter for products whose orig_price is less than (lt) 130

```
 $collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
        array('attribute'=>'orig_price','lt'=>'130'),
    ));
```

While this will filter by a name that equals one thing OR another.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');  
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('orig_price');
```

//filter for products who name is equal (eq) to Widget A, or equal (eq) to Widget B

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'name','eq'=>'Widget A'),
    array('attribute'=>'name','eq'=>'Widget B'),        
));
```

A full list of the supported short conditionals (eq,lt, etc.) can be found in the _**getConditionSql** method in **lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php**

Finally, all Magento collections may be iterated over (the base collection class implements on of the the iterator interfaces). This is how you'll grab your products once filters are set.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');  
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('orig_price');
```

//filter for products who name is equal (eq) to Widget A, or equal (eq) to Widget B

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('name'=>'orig_price','eq'=>'Widget A'),
    array('name'=>'orig_price','eq'=>'Widget B'),       
));

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    //var_dump($product);
    var_dump($product->getData());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can use ProductRepository for getting Complete Product Information

private $productRepository;
public function __construct(
\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
$this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function getProductDataUsingSku($sku)
{
$productData=$this->productRepository->get($sku);
print_r($productData);
die();
}